# VSCode: What is the best way to commit a list of extensions to be used by VSCode in a project?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I'd like to standardize the use of some VSCode extensions in a project. Sure I can commit the `.vscode/settings.json` file and the Python Extension will use flake8. But I'd like to make it easy to install and activate an extension in VSCode.

As an exemple, I really like the stack analysis bash extension [Shell Check](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=timonwong.shellcheck). I can commit the configuration activating it, but if the other developer does not have it installed, it wouldn't work.

Is it possible to commit a file to my project listing a bunch of extensions to be automatically installed?

Comment: If you use devcontainer.json with its remote development environment (like GitHub Codespaces), you can easily define what extensions to install for a project, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add extension recommendations to `.vscode` see:
[Workspace recommended extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions)